# Why can my azure PubSub subscriber not recieve from my publisher

Tags: azure, azure-web-pubsub

I am seeking to use groups within Azure PubSub, but it appears that either my publisher and subscriber are not both joining the same group somehow, or my serverless functions are not handling the broadcast after the message gets published. The service works if I publish without the groups implemented, but once I attempted to add groups I can see messages hitting the live trace tool on azure, but no messages being sent out after, so I suspect I may be missing something in my azure functions, but am not sure what that would be.

Publisher code:

```
const hub = "simplechat";
let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient("Endpoint=endpointURL", hub);

// by default it uses `application/json`, specify contentType as `text/plain` if you want plain-text
const group = service.group("myGroup");
group.sendToAll('Hello World', { contentType: "text/plain" });
```

Subscriber code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const { WebPubSubServiceClient } = require('@azure/web-pubsub');
var printer = require("printer/lib");
var util = require('util');

async function main() {
  const hub = "simplechat";
  let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient("EndpointEndpointURL", hub);
  const group = service.group("myGroup");
  let token = await service.getClientAccessToken();
  let ws = new WebSocket(token.url, 'json.webpubsub.azure.v1');
  ws.on('open', () => console.log('connected'));
  ws.on('message', data => {
    console.log('Message received: %s', data);
  });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the part of joining your subscriber to the group.

The simplest way is to give the connection a user name and call `addUser` to add the connection to the group when the connection is connected:

```js
async function main() {
  const hub = "simplechat";
  let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient("EndpointEndpointURL", hub);
  const group = service.group("myGroup");
  let token = await service.getClientAccessToken({ userId: "user1"});
  // with this approach, the WebSocket actually does not need to be 'json.webpubsub.azure.v1' subprotocol, a simple WebSocket connection also works
  let ws = new WebSocket(token.url, 'json.webpubsub.azure.v1');
  ws.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected');
    group.addUser("user1");
    }
  );
  ws.on('message', data => {
    console.log('Message received: %s', data);
  });
}
```

Or you can wait until received the [Connected Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/reference-json-webpubsub-subprotocol#connected) to get the `connectionId` of the connection and call `addConnection` to add the subscriber to the group.

Another way, since you are already using `json.webpubsub.azure.v1` protocol, would be that your subscriber to send the [joinGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/reference-json-webpubsub-subprotocol#join-groups) request:

```js
async function main() {
  const hub = "simplechat";
  let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient("EndpointEndpointURL", hub);
  // make sure you set the joinLeaveGroup role for the group
  let token = await service.getClientAccessToken({
    roles: ['webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.myGroup']
  });
  let ws = new WebSocket(token.url, 'json.webpubsub.azure.v1');
  let ackId = 0;
  ws.on('open', () => { 
        console.log('connected');
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          type: 'joinGroup',
          group: 'myGroup',
          ackId: ++ackId,
        }));
     });
  ws.on('message', data => {
    console.log('Message received: %s', data);
  });
}
```

When your subscriber receives the [AckMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-web-pubsub/reference-json-webpubsub-subprotocol#ack-response) for this `joinGroup` action, your subscriber successfully joins the group.

Comment: Do groups have a life span, or will it continue to exist once declared, if it has a lifespan how is it managed?

Comment: Group is more like a "group session". The "group session" starts when some connection joins it, and the "group session" ends when no connection is in it.

Comment: So if I run a client on a raspberry pi it can just sit in the group session forever or is that an expensive/inefficient  thing to do? My intention here is to have pubsub notify raspberry pi client when a file is available for it to download

Comment: It can listen to the group session forever, it is little cost from the service aspect of view. From the client's aspect of view, the effort is to maintain the WebSocket connection, there is no additional cost introduced when subscribed to a group. And don't forget to rejoin the group if the client is disconnected and then reconnect.