# Connecting Azure Web PubSub Client Disconnects others

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-pubsub

I have a scenario where I have 2 c# ClientWebSocket connected to an azure Web PubSub. They can communicate fine. I then disconnect client 2 (call CloseAsync()). The Azure web trigger for disconnect works, and informs client 1 that client 2 has disconnected. I then connect client 2 again and client 1 will abort. Catching an exception in client 1's receive loop says the ssl stream has been disposed. I did not call abort or dispose on client 1. I assume this is because Azure is closing the connection service side...

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix this? I would like clients to be able to join and leave as they please.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with me making several client connections from the same machine?

Comment: [Why can my azure PubSub subscriber not recieve from my publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242320/why-can-my-azure-pubsub-subscriber-not-recieve-from-my-publisher), [Missing pubsub messages between client disconnect and reconnect](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webpubsub/issues/198) and [azure-webpubsub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webpubsub/issues)

Comment: Is it possible to repro the issue? Could you update the question with a mini repro-able project? Client 2 disconnect/connect should not impact connected Client 1.

Comment: when using "subprotocol" when disconnect the reason might contain some useful info. You can also try the [livetrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/howto-troubleshoot-resource-logs#launch-the-live-trace-tool) tool to see if any useful logs are provided

Comment: The issue seems to be related to how frequently client 1 was sending messages. If I send more than 3 per second it's connection aborts. The subprotocol doesn't provide any explanation in that scenario.

Could it be that the service disconnects at a certain message rate threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with Azure WebPubSub.

I was making multiple calls to `System.Net.WebSockets.SendAsync` which makes it abort. As documented "Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each ClientWebSocket object in parallel."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).